# How to align text in an anchor element

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

I'm working on a website and that website has a menu, I had some problems getting it to work in IE11 got that figured out but now I run into a new problem.

I want the text in the 'menu items' (the `<li>` items) to be in the middle.

I've made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9hkutz/1/)

I've given `.menu-main-container` a 75px height but on the website itself it has a variable height.

Ultimately I want the text in the center and the `<a>` element to have the same height as the `.menu-main-container`element for the purpose of styling the submenu's (which aren't included in the fiddle cause that's not the problem)

I can't use `table`and `table-cell` stylings

EDIT: note: this has to work in all browsers!

HTML

```
<div class="menu-main-container">
    <ul id="menu-main" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-1"> <a href=#>Item1</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-2"> <a href=#>Item2</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-3"> <a href=#>Item3</a>

        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-4"> <a href=#>Item4</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.menu-main-container {
    height: 75px;
}
#menu-main {
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
    white-space : nowrap;
    font-size : 0;
    position : relative;
    height : 100%;
}
#menu-main * {
    font-size : 16px;
    list-style-type : none;
    padding : 0;
    margin : 0;
}
#menu-main a {
    text-transform : capitalize;
    text-decoration : none;
    color : #000000;
    display : block;
}
#menu-main > li {
    display : inline-block;
    width : 16.6%;
    text-align : center;
    float : left;
    height : 100%;
}
#menu-main > li:hover {
    background-color : #003cb3;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see demo: `http://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/1adsca8u/

I remove `height: 75px;` of **.menu-main-container** class and **padding-top , padding-bottom** in **li tag**

Update your css code:

```
.menu-main-container {
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    display: table;
    width:100%;
}

#menu-main > li {
    display : table;
    width : 16.6%;
    text-align : center;
    float : left;
    height : 100%;
    padding-top:28px;
    padding-bottom:28px;
    max-height:75px;
}
```

Comment: Can't use `table` and `table-cell`styling

Comment: @LiamdeHaas I change table code to inline-block. see demo: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/alihesari/fh8uzqg2/)

Comment: Noticed the 'static'values with `padding-bottom``padding-top`and `max-height`is there a way to do it with percentages?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66390/discussion-between-rockstar-and-liam-de-haas).

Comment: Yes it is, maybe change your answer so I can accept

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `line-height: 75px` to the `a` element.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9hkutz/5/)

Comment: problem with that is that it's a fixed line height, is it possible to do it variable? so that when i resize the page it stays in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Try with this one.

```
#menu-main a {
    text-transform: capitalize;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000000;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 24px 0;
    }
```

Comment: This leaves a `hoverable`area beneath the element I don't want (ie you can hover beneath the element and still get the background to turn blue)

Comment: ie you can hover beneath the element and still get the background to turn blue) – @LiamdeHaas

This not make sense to me

Comment: Added a border so you can see for yourself [here](http://jsfiddle.net/dk9hkutz/8/). If you hover beneath the red border it still 'activates' the menu-item if you were hovering over it (which you actuallu are but it's not visually correct)

Answer (score 0):

Update the CSS rule for "#menu-main a" to below:

```
#menu-main a {
color: #000000;
display: block;
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
text-transform: capitalize;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(0%, -50%);}
```

It will automatically picks up the height of container.

Comment: It doesn't pick up the `transform`

Comment: IE supports transform property: [Tranform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/jj127312%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Then why does it give me a red line when I inspect the element? see [here](http://imgur.com/xeDj116) and why doesn't it show properly? [how it should be](http://imgur.com/Ih6siGE), [how it is in ie11](http://imgur.com/GtdpvgD)

Comment: My IE is recognizing it properly. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66391/discussion-between-liam-de-haas-and-sachin-dhir).